# CodeTyphon, Typhon32 Big IDE Not Starting

Tags: freepascal, lazarus, codetyphon

I have compiled and recompiled the big IDE of Typhon32 numerous times and still the big IDE will not start, It doesnt even give a warning all that happens is the splash screen loads and then nothing happens not even a process of Lazarus is running. i dont have anything else installed for example no extra cross compiles have been installed and so on.  Please Help I would like to start using this innovative tool. Thanks: Gareth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove all references to other fpc and/or lazarus installations from your PATH. Probably the CT batch installer finds another fpc ad uses this other one instead the compiler packaged with CodeTyphon